# Can Nikola bootstrap Jinja2 theme render navigation dropdown menu in nikola?

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying out the Nikola static site-generator for a test site and I am coming across this problem. I am submitting both the code and the error message.

This is my code for the menu (straight from the Nikola Handbook)

```
NAVIGATION_LINKS = {
    DEFAULT_LANG: (
        ('/archive.html', 'Archives'),
        ('/categories/index.html', 'Tags'),
        ('/rss.xml', 'RSS'),
        ((('/foo', 'FOO'),
          ('/bar', 'BAR')), 'BAZ'),
    ),
}
```

This is the error generated:

```
TaskError - taskid:render_tags:output/categories/index.html
PythonAction Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/satish/.virtualenvs/nikola/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/doit/action.py", line 360, in execute
    returned_value = self.py_callable(*self.args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/satish/.virtualenvs/nikola/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nikola/nikola.py", line 639, in render_template
    template_name, None, local_context)
  File "/home/satish/.virtualenvs/nikola/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nikola/plugins/template/jinja.py", line 74, in render_template
    output = template.render(**context)
  File "/home/satish/.virtualenvs/nikola/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 969, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/home/satish/.virtualenvs/nikola/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 742, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "themes/bootstrap3-jinja/templates/tags.tmpl", line 2, in top-level template code
    {% extends 'base.tmpl' %}
  File "themes/bootstrap3-jinja/templates/base.tmpl", line 41, in top-level template code
    {{ bootstrap.html_navigation_links() }}
  File "themes/bootstrap3-jinja/templates/bootstrap_helper.tmpl", line 93, in template
    {% if rel_link(permalink, url) == "#" %}
  File "/home/satish/.virtualenvs/nikola/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nikola/nikola.py", line 901, in rel_link
    dst = urljoin(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 253, in urljoin
    urlparse(url, bscheme, allow_fragments)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 135, in urlparse
    tuple = urlsplit(url, scheme, allow_fragments)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 174, in urlsplit
    i = url.find(':')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'find'
```

I am using the `bootstrap3-jinja` theme.

I hope that I have homed on to the correct part of the code which is generating the error.

Please (someone) add `nikola` as a tag. I don't have the requisite reputation to create it.
From what I have tested `Nikola` is a awesome great tool for blogs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Nikola.  It’s been fixed on the GitHub master.  Please:

- remove your `base-jinja`, `bootstrap-jinja`, `bootstrap3-jinja` themes from the local `themes/` subdirectory — they are shipped with Nikola since v7.0.0
- upgrade to the current GitHub master

PS. StackOverflow is not the best place to ask questions at; you’re more likely to get answers on the mailing list or by reporting an issue on GitHub.